# Fitch proof (constructing formal proof)

Tags: logic

The two premises are A → B, ¬C ∨ ¬B. I have to get ¬(C ∧ A).
How can I get the results? I tried to make a subproof with (C ∧ A). But I can't go further.

Comment: The assumption $(C \land A)$ is correct. Unpack it to derive $A$ and $C$ by $\land$-elim and derive a contradicition.

Comment: If after the assumption you "can't go further", it may helps to review the inference rules

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to derive a contradiction from the assumption to introduce a negation.   You have a *conditional* and a *disjunction* in your premises, and a *conjunction* in your assumption.   Use the relevant rules of elimination.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A\to B\\\neg C\vee\neg B}{\fitch{C\wedge A}{C\qquad\wedge\mathsf E\\A\qquad\wedge\mathsf E\\B\qquad{\to}\mathsf E\\\vdots\\\bot\qquad\vee\mathsf E}\\\neg(C\wedge A)\qquad\neg\mathsf I}$